# DefaultAzureCredentials fails to pickup credentials in MangedIdentity AKS

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-managed-identity

Based on the documentation given [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/master/sdk/identity/Azure.Identity) . When using DefaultAzureCredentials() it will check for environment variables then ManagedIdentity and so on. In my test, I have deployed system Managed Service Identity AKS. I have deployed a c# application that tries to connect to Keyvault via application using the below code

```
   var keyClient = new KeyClient(vaultUri: new Uri(keyVaultUrl),
            credential: new DefaultAzureCredential(true));
        

        Response<KeyVaultKey> response = keyClient.GetKey("somekey");
```

On deploying my application to the AKS cluster, it fails with the below error -

```
Unhandled exception. Azure.Identity.AuthenticationFailedException: DefaultAzureCredential failed to retrieve a token from the included credentials.
- EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured.
- ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. The requested identity has not been assigned to this resource.
Status: 400 (Bad Request)
Content:
{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Identity not found"}
```

Based on the documentation my application should have picked up the managed identity from AKS cluster and be able to connect with Keyvault to fetch the values. But for some reason its throwing this error. Please could someone guide me if I m missing something.

Comment: have you explored pod identities ? you can specify pod identity to give access to keyvault in this case.

Comment: I have checked the Pod identities and I wasnt looking for that level of granular level of authorisation for my PoC. To start with  I was thinking if any pod in AKS is able to access Keyvault. TBH, I dont think it even reached to that stage, it failed when it executed DefaultAzureCredentials() statement.

Comment: How have you deployed "system Managed Service Identity AKS"? Can you share a reference?

Comment: using an ARM template from github quickstart templates, instead of setting the "Identity" to serviceprincipal I have changed it to "SystemAssigned"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Managed identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/use-managed-identity) used to create the AKS cluster is for the control plane and not your worker nodes or applications. Control plane uses that managed identity to create requested cloud resources like load balancer, scale-sets, routes, and other. If you want your applications to use a managed identity, recommend approach is to deploy [aad-pod-identities](https://github.com/Azure/aad-pod-identity) which gives you app level authorization scheme. Alternatively, you can also enable [managed identity for the VMSS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/qs-configure-portal-windows-vmss) based node-pools. In the later case, Azure will create a new system managed identity for the node-pool with the same name and you can use that to establish authorization between KeyVault or other services.

Comment: I have deployed my AKS cluster using the System managed identity for node-pool.I gave permissions for the system managed identity to access Keyvault. But when my aspnet core application starts in AKS, it tries to connect to Keyvault and ends up with error as mentioned in my question.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. System managed identity is not for the pods to use but for the controls plane. Please go through the answer one more time.

Comment: For anyone using Asp.net core Apis and using managed identities for KeyVault access within AKS. This answer should work.